# Show that Riemann Surface is connected?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I was reading Artin's Alegbra when this question came into my mind.

Consider $f(t,x)=x^{2}-t$ , The locus X of zeros in $\mathbb C^{2}$ of a polynomial is called Riemann  surface of f.

I understood how book gives description of Riemann surfaces as branched coverings.
I have the following question, Is X connected or not ?

Comment: "Riemann", not Reimann in the title.

Comment: $X$ is the image of $\mathbb{C}$ under the map $z \mapsto (z^2,z)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sir ,Am I right in saying that , If  I show that this map is continuous then since $\mathbb C$ is connected the image will also be connected.

Comment: Yes, but the continuity of that map should be known. The thing that does need a bit of work is to show that indeed $p(\mathbb{C}) = X$ (where $p$ is the map in question).

Comment: @DanielFischer But Sir I have doubt , When I was geometrically thinking of this Riemann surface , as mentioned in book we deleted certain points , Artin called him "bad  points ". I think more precisely we have to see the the image of complex numbers with certain "bad points" deleted.

Comment: The exceptional points do not affect connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero locus of a monic (in $x$) polynomial $P(x,y)=0$ in $C^2$ is always path-connected. The multiset of roots varies continuously in $y$ for any suitable distance between multisets, such as edit distance based on a metric in $C$.  If you want to trace the path of a particular $x$ as a function of $y$ this is not hard to extract from a given path of all the $x$'s.

Comment: Sir , Can you kindly mention the source from where I can read the proof of the statement that zero locus of a monic polynomial $P(x,y)=0$ is always path connected in $\mathbb C^{2}$. Actually sir I am asking this as apart of Artin I don't know what are other sources from where I can read about these stuff.

Comment: I have no idea about a source, but the proof is sketched in the answer: put a distance on multisets so that path motion between different values of $y$ is continuous in "multiset space of $x$'s".  If necessary construct a section of that motion that isolates a single root, though it's not clear to me that this is logically necessary (it could be).

Comment: Sir Can you clarify what do you mean by "multisets " and "multiset space of x's"

Comment: Standard term for "sets with repeated elements allowed, and the amount of repetition recorded" (because polynomials can have repeated roots).